# Can I use 2 phase commit between 2 queue connections

Tags: jboss, jms, ibm-mq, mq, jboss-mdb

Recently I need to develop JBOSS application which receives IBM MQ Message.

It seems like use wmq.jmsra.rar and Message Driven Bean is a most common solution.
But I'm a little bit uncertain who is responsible of this Resouce.
IBM? or Redhat?

I'd rather develop my own queue connector daemon which read message from IBM MQ and send to JBOSS MDB using JMS.

In this case, I need 2 phase commit, to commit simultaneously both IBM MQ side and JBOSS side. Can I use something like XATransaction on this process? Is there any example on Web if it's possible.

Sorry, I couldn't find any example so far.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wmq.jmsa.rar is released by IBM. Its found as part of the product.  Go with the latest release WMQ 7.5 if possible.
WMQ supports XA transaction. It can participate as a resource manager in a 2 phase transaction coordinated by an external transaction monitor/application server.

Sample programs for Java XA transaction are not found with the installation. (I know I have seen C and Cobol XA samples).

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.mq.dev.doc%2Fq023590_.htm

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.mq.dev.doc%2Fq031500_.htm

You will require a local qmgr (application should run on the same server as qmgr to connect in bindings mode) or extended transactional client to connect to a remote qmgr using XA transactions.

Comment: Thanks nsupathy! It means first I need to configure my Queue Manager in bindings mode because I still depend on IBM's evaluation and the budget has not been authorized yet. I'm still looking for sample source code to use XATransaction with MQ. Is it easier if I dig into source code inside wmq.jmsra.rar with some decompiler? I wonder.